# Can addresses of unmodified locals wind up corrupted in setjmp/longjmp?

Tags: c, clang, language-lawyer, setjmp, address-sanitizer

If one winds up in the situation of being stuck using setjmp/longjmp *(don't ask)*, then there are lots of nice warnings from the compiler about when you might be doing something wrong.

But with a `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` build while using [Address Sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) in Clang, I wound up with a case roughly parallel to:

```
void outer() {
    jmp_buf buf;
    ERR error;

    if (setjmp(buf) ? helper(&error) : FALSE) {
        // process whatever helper decided to write into error
        return;
    }

    // do the stuff you wanted to guard that may longjmp.
    // error is never modified
}
```

On a longjmp, looking into the `helper` stack frame the error pointer is null.  If I look in the `outer()` frame it says error has been "optimized out".

It's puzzling because I'm compiling with `-O0`  So the "optimized out" is weird for it to be saying.  But as with most things *longjmp-y*, I wonder what keeps the compiler from possibly making a decision on what register it's going to put the error address in ahead of time...then having that be invalidated.

Is address sanitizer punking me, or do I actually have to write something like:

```
void outer() {
    jmp_buf buf;
    ERR error;
    volatile ERR* error_ptr = &error;

    if (setjmp(buf) ? helper(error_ptr) : FALSE) {
        // process whatever helper decided to write into error
        return;
    }

    // do the stuff you wanted to guard that may longjmp.
    // error is never modified
}
```

As I research this, I've noticed that `jmp_buf`s are not locals in any of the examples I see.  Is that something you can't do?  :-/

---

**NOTE:** See @AnT's answer and comments below for the "language-lawyer" issue about the `setjmp() ? ... : ...` construct.  But what I actually had going on here turned out to be a broken longjmp call that was after the function exited.  Per [`longjmp()` docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp) (also: common sense), that's *definitely* broken; I just didn't realize that's what had happened:

> If the function that called setjmp has exited, the behavior is undefined (in other words, only long jumps up the call stack are allowed)

Comment: "On a longjmp, looking into the helper stack frame the error pointer is null"... Can you provide a more elaborate explanation of what you are looking at and when? A minimal compilable example that reproduces the behavior, perhaps?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the "helper()"'s function content. It the function isn't actually using its argument (e.g. an empy function or a plain printf("Error!\n")), the complier could decide to throw "error" variable away since it's useless. But the weird thing is that optimizations have been explicitly disabled. Uhm...

Comment: That's strange. The value of `error` is indeterminate, but the variable should still exist. I don't think looking at code "roughly parallel to" failing code is going to be enough; you'll have to post an MCVE.

Comment: @AnT While MVCEs are usually quite important, establishing one here would require describing how to configure address sanitizer and a lot of other junk.  I'm looking for a "language lawyer" example--and provide the pattern for the purposes of framing the discussion.  Reducing it to a repro example will only tell me whose bug it is; and I need the spec answer for it to matter.  I need to know what it's *supposed* to do--not what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason the `helper` call is "embedded" into the controlling expression of `if` through `?:` operator? This is actually a violation of the language requirements that says

> **7.13.1.1 The setjmp macro**
>
> **4** An invocation of the setjmp macro shall appear only in one of the
>   following contexts:
>
> — the entire controlling expression of a selection
>   or iteration statement;
>
> — one operand of a relational or equality
>   operator with the other operand an integer constant expression, with
>   the resulting expression being the entire controlling expression of
>   a selection or iteration statement;
>
> — the operand of a unary !
>   operator with the resulting expression being the entire controlling
>   expression of a selection or iteration statement; or
>
> — the entire
>   expression of an expression statement (possibly cast to void).
>
> **5** If
>   the invocation appears in any other context, the behavior is
>   undefined.

The whole point of that requirement is to make sure the "unpredictable" return from `setjmp`, triggered by `longjmp`, should not land in the middle of an expression evaluation, i.e. in an unsequenced context. In your specific example it is rather obvious that from the point of view of abstract C language, variable `error` cannot possibly be changed by `setjmp` call, which opens the door for many optimizations.

It is hard to say what happened here, since `helper` receives a pointer `&error`, not `error`'s direct value. At the surface everything seems fine from practical point of view. But formally the behavior is undefined.

In your case, you should not try to fix thing by making variables `volatile`, but rather should simplify the context the `setjmp` is used in to conform with the above requirements. Something along the lines of

```
if (setjmp(buf) != 0) {
  helper(&error);
  ...
  return;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I was actually wondering about that as I read more into this.  The reason is that in the code it's done as a macro (I just expanded it here for the simplified case).  The macro wants to do a bit of processing before it gives back control to the branch.  Not legal, eh?

Comment: @HostileFork: Apparently not.

Comment: Interestingly that section you cite made it to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/setjmp) *(should have looked there, but it's C!)*.  All the C-related hits for setjmp [like this one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) don't seem to mention it... and it's not in [Wikipedia article's caveats and limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h#Caveats_and_limitations) but buried under an example.  Someone should... fix that.  :-)

Comment: I think para 3 of ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.13.2.1 The longjmp function is relevant too: _All accessible objects have values, and all other components of the abstract machine
have state, as of the time the `longjmp` function was called, except that the values of
objects of automatic storage duration that are local to the function containing the
invocation of the corresponding `setjmp` macro that do not have volatile-qualified type
and have been changed between the `setjmp` invocation and `longjmp` call are
indeterminate._  I think `volatile ERR error;` would be sufficient, though.

Comment: The behaviour is not so much 'not legal' as 'undefined behaviour', and that's bad.

Comment: I wonder why the Standard doesn't allow an assignment to a `volatile` local variable as an option for the `setjmp` return?  Yes, compilers may have to work a little to ensure that such an assignment "works", but without the ability to capture the value passed to `longjmp` it doesn't seem very useful.  One could say `int val=0; switch(setjmp(...)) { case 0: main_code; break; case 1: val=1; break; case 2: val=2; break; case 3: val=3; break; ...} but that seems really incredibly hokey.

Comment: Even if some machines couldn't handle a store to a volatile, I would think storing to a volatile should at minimum be a standard form of extension that could be tested for; like comparisons involving unrelated pointers, it would make a lot more sense to say that code can use such features on platforms than provide them, than to require that even programs written for platforms that could easily provide such features must use klunky workarounds to deal with their absence.

Comment: It turned out that the more immediate problem was that the macros were obscuring that I was doing something else illegal... which is that there was a scope where one setjmp was made that exited before the longjmp was executed.  I'd managed to overlook it (though I knew you couldn't do that).  So yes, an MVCE would have helped me fix this problem... but thanks for the language-lawyer answer on the other point, which is important to know the answer to!